# Scaling A node js server which runs python

Tags: node.js, express, queue

I have created a node server using express which run python program which run on gpu in background to process the inputs/request. I am able to display the output on browser. How can I make my node server salable to handle many concurrent. Should I use queue for handling requests? If yes how do I start? I need a definite approach.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js by default is setup to be highly performant due to it's asynchronous event loop.

However, for multi-core systems, you could look at the cluster module to scale out your api: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Note that your Node.js backend should ideally be stateless for scalability.